# What's the Weight of Evidence

Tags: st.statistics

Here, "Weight of evidence" (WOE) is a common term in the published scientific and policy-making literature, most often seen in the context of risk assessment. defined by:

$w(e : h) = \ln\frac{p(e|h)}{p(e|\overline{h})}$

where e is evidence, h is hypothesis.

Now, I want to know what's the mainly difference between PMI (Pointwise mutual information)

$pmi(e,h)=\log\frac{p(e,h)}{p(e)*p(h)}$

Comment: The "definitely difference" is that one is PMI.

Comment: could you explain more clearly, thanks!

Comment: There is a http://stats.stackexchange.com/ at SE, which may be useful.

Comment: @Charlie: First, I was pointing out the "definitely difference" typo; second, you should say "the main difference between PMI (Pointwise Mutual Information) and WOE".

Comment: One difference is that $w(e:h)$ is a little more symmetric; it merely changes sign if you replace $h$ by $\overline h$.  In fact, $w(e:h)=pmi(e,h)-pmi(e,\overline h)$.  

This question strikes me as neither clear enough nor at the right level for MO, so I'll vote to close.